# How to remove physicsBody/ stop responding to gravity after sprite reaches a specific position?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skscene

So I want my sprite to move with gravity until it reaches a specific location and then it should stop responding to gravity and stay there. How can I do that? Thanks in advance

I want it so that it stops once it reaches target position

```
sprite.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: sprite.size.width/2)
if sprite.position == newPosition {
sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false}
```

doesn't work

Comment: So it should a certain point then stop? Or collide with another sprite then stop?

Comment: You might want to throw some code in showing how you're configuring your sprite, too.

Comment: Why not just use an skaction such as moveTo or moveBy? If you don't mind me asking

Comment: What function is this code in? You'll have to be very lucky for your sprite's `position` to equal some specific `CGPoint` - they are very small. You would be better checking in `update()` if the sprite 'contains' the `newPosition` or using an SKAction as sicvayne suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing something like this

```
 override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    //In this case, you can just change self.size.height/2 with whatever position you want.
    if sprite.position.y <= self.size.height/2{

        sprite.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        sprite.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false


    }


}
```

In this case, I created a sprite that is positioned way up top with gravity set to true. In `override func update`, I am stating that once my sprite has reached this certain location, I want it to be static.